# Are there errors in this encrytion overview?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

The aim here is to make a verified client for my server. The server should know that the request coming from the client is secure.

Here's my first pass:

- The user enters a password.
  The password is sent plain text to the server.
- The server creates priv and pub keys from that password.
- The client does the same making sure to save the priv key securely (using the Web Crypto API).
- The server then hashes the password, maybe using a separate process, and saves it to the user's record.
- They both discard the password.

Now the client sends requests to the server with a hashed portion of the request's content using its priv key.

If the server's pub key cannot decrypt the hash it knows this request was not sent from a verified client and will ignore it.

Comment: If you are using HTTPS, the server can request a certificate from the client, which you gave him to be secure. In this case you would know the client and you would know that it is secure. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake with Client-authenticated handshake. Would this work for you?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using TLS, otherwise the first step doesn't make sense. Sorry to say this, but this scheme that you present just registers an unknown client to the server which makes the client known to the server. You can achieve that in a much simpler fashion by just generating a random key at the client send it along to the server which hashes it and stores the hash. There is no need for generating private keys from password (this is really hard/impossible to do with most crypto libraries).

Comment: Yes TLS is a given. I'm pretty sure you can make a pub priv key from any random string, why would a password be particularly difficult?